# Projecting entities from one dbcontext to another best practices

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two databasecontexts `FooContext`, `BarContext`.
For `FooContext`, when certain entities in the dbSet changes, I need to project these entities to related entities in `BarContext`. I am looking at the best ways to implement such a job.

My current attempt involves inheriting an interface for the relevant entities, filtering these out in overridden `FooContext.SaveChangesAsync()` before calling a separate mapper (using dependencyInjection) to update the relevant tables in `BarContext`

```cs
// Baz.cs
public class Baz : IProjectedEntity {
   // baz-definition
}

// FooContext.cs
public class FooContext : DbContext  {

    private IJobSpawner _jobSpawner;

    public FooContext(IJobSpawner jobSpawner){
        _jobSpawner=jobSpawner;
    }

    public DbSet<Baz> Baz {get;}
    
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var projections = ChangeTracker
            .Entries<IProjectedEntity>()
            .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
            .Select(e => e.Entity).ToList();

        int changes = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await _jobSpawner.ProjectEntities(projections);
        return changes;
    }

}
```

Then the implementation of `IJobSpawner` takes dependency on `BarContext` and does the necessary mappings.

1. Is this a bad idea?
2. What is an alternative way of doing this?

I have also played a bith with the thought of defining an attribute for class properties, such that projections only happen if certain properties is changed

**note** : The method i have proposed does work, but I feel there should be a better, less cluttered way of achieving the same result. I don't like having to much internal logic in the context

Comment: how time critical is to keep these DBs in sync? Can your use case tolerate some delay and eventual consitency?

Comment: Sync is pretty important, but there might be some slack in delay. Hovewer it is important that this job *is* done at some point